# Infinite loop React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I don't understand why I'm getting infinite loop in 
**useClick** I see that I change state value inside **useEffect** using **setVal** but useEffect should work only on onClick as specified in second param. I thought that it is because the param onClick i pass is memoized but the callback is not called(i checked that using **console.log('go set')**

```
function useClick(onClick, setVal, val) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Click');
    setVal(val + 1);
  }, [onClick]);
}

const Home = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState(0);
  const incrementOnClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log('go set');
    setVal(val + 1);
  } , [setVal, val]);
  useClick(incrementOnClick, setVal, val);
  return <div>
    <div>{val}</div>
    <button onClick={incrementOnClick}>Click me</button>
 </div>
}
```

Comment: I think the loop it's due to the call of `useClick` inside `Home` Component: `Home` calls `useClick`, inside `useClick` you change the `val` property of `Home`, thus the `Home` Component` it's re-rendered, thus the function `Home` it's called again, thus `useClick` is executed again.. And there is the loop

Comment: Looking at your code I'm not sure what your trying to do.  Remember that every time `Home` gets rendered your going to get another instance of `incrementOnClick`, so passing that as the last parameter to `useEffect` is not going to do anything.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm using the useCallback function to avoid

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`val` and `setVal` will change on every render, which in turn will cause `incrementOnClick` to become a new function reference, and your `useClick` effect will always be invoked.

You could instead give a function as first argument to `setVal`. This function gets the current `val` as argument and returns the new value. This way `incrementOnClick` will always be the same function.

```js
const { useEffect, useState, useCallback } = React;

function useClick(onClick, setVal, val) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Click");
    setVal(val + 1);
  }, [onClick]);
}

const Home = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);
  const incrementOnClick = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("go set");
    setVal(val => val + 1);
  }, []);

  useClick(incrementOnClick, setVal, val);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{val}</div>
      <button onClick={incrementOnClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

The code above shows how you could get away from the infinite loop and could be valuable for experimentation, but most of it isn't necessary. You could write the same functionality like this instead:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Home = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(1);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{val}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setVal(val + 1)}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at what your trying to do, I believe your missing one of the most useful features of Hooks & React, and that's composition.

Here is an example of what you have done, but just creating another component called `<IncrementButton/>`,  to me it just makes the code much easier to understand / debug.  Custom hooks are great, but for doing this I believe it's the wrong tool..

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const IncrementButton = props => {
  const {val, setVal, children} = props;
  return <button
    onClick={() => setVal(val + 1)}
  >{children}</button>;
}

const Home = () => {
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{val}</div>
      <IncrementButton val={val} setVal={setVal}>
        Click me
      </IncrementButton>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Sure, this question was mostly to ask if I'm understanding hooks. Of course the final button would look separated like you wrote. Thanks