# React Hook useEffect dependency issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, use-effect

I'm getting a warning message on my app and I've tried lots of things to remove it, without success. Error Message:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'updateUserData'.
>   Either include it or remove the dependency array 
>   react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I don't want to exclude that with a comment to avoid the issue, but I want to fix it in a "best practices" way.

I want to call that updater function and get my component updated, so I can share that context in other components.

So... what i'm doing wrong? (any code review about the rest is very welcomed!)

Thanks a million!

If I add [] as the 2nd parameter of useEffect I get the warning, and removing it I get an inifinite loop.

Also adding [updateuserData] gets an infinite loop.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import UserContext from "./UserContext";


interface iProps {
    children: React.ReactNode
}

const UserProvider: React.FC<iProps> = (props) => {
    // practice details
    const [userState, setUserState] = useState({
        id'',
        name: ''
    });

    // practice skills
    const [userProfileState, setuserProfileState] = useState([]);

    // user selection
    const [userQuestionsState, setuserQuestionsState] = useState({});


    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={{
            data: {
                user: userState,
                userProfile: userProfileState,
                questions: userQuestionsState
            },
            updateuserData: (id : string) => {
                 // call 3 services with axios in parallel
                 // update state of the 3 hooks
            }
        }}
        >
            {props.children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default UserProvider;
```

```
const UserPage: React.FC<ComponentProps> = (props) => {


    const {data : {user, profile, questions}, updateUserData}: any = useContext(UserContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        // update information
        updateUserData("abcId")
    }, []);



    return <div>...</div>

}
```

The idea is the following:

- I have a context
- I created provider for that content
- that context exposes the data and an updater function
- I use that provider in a component with the useEffect hook and I get the warning
- I want to keep all the logic about fetching and updating the context inside the provider, so I don't replicate it all over the other components that are needing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Infinite loop React hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023350/infinite-loop-react-hooks)

Comment: When do you want userPage to call updateUserData? Just once on mount? If so, then an empty array is the correct second param, and you'll use an eslint-ignore to dismiss the lint warning.

Comment: I want to run it once, when it get's mounted and also when the route changes (i.e.: when the props.match.params.userId changes)

Comment: thanks @WillJenkins ! sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the infinite loop is caused by the fact that your context is updating, which is causing your component to be re-rendered, which is updating your context, which is causing your component to be re-rendered. Adding the dependency should prevent this loop, but in your case it isn't because when your context updates, a brand new `updateuserData` is being provided, so the ref equality check detects a change and triggers an update when you don't want it to.

One solution would be to change how you create `updateUserState` in your `UserProvider`, using e.g. `useCallback` to pass the same function unless one of the dependencies changes:

```
const UserProvider: React.FC<iProps> = (props) => {
  // practice details
  const [userState, setUserState] = useState({
      id'',
      name: ''
  });

  // practice skills
  const [userProfileState, setuserProfileState] = useState([]);

  // user selection
  const [userQuestionsState, setuserQuestionsState] = useState({});
  const updateuserData = useCallback(id=>{
    // call your services
  }, [userState, userProfileState, userQuestionsState])

  return (
      <UserContext.Provider value={{
          data: {
              user: userState,
              userProfile: userProfileState,
              questions: userQuestionsState
          },
          updateuserData
      }}
      >
          {props.children}
      </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: This answer looks great! Actually, this looks like a great pattern to store simple state and share it among components. I added the changes on the  Provider and it works. On the UserPage, I added the [updateUserData] and it is working now as expected without issues. Thanks so much!

Comment: Btw... have you ever used this kind of pattern (having the context, providing the data and the updater function) ?

Comment: I haven't seen this pattern, but it's pretty similar to using redux